# How to put the received sms in a string attribute

Tags: android

I wrote a program that displayed the receiving sms. I am a trouble putting the sms into a string variable.

```
  Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
       msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
       for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
           msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
           str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
           str += " :";
           str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
           str += "\n";        
       }

       //---display the new SMS message---

       Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       Intent intentHome = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
       intentHome.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(intentHome);
```

How can I put the entire message into one string variable 
I have tried this,,,

`String S = new String(str) ;`

it didn't work. 
Also, I want to use the string to setText into a ViewText Variable

Comment: What happens if you do String S = str; ?

Comment: In another class I wrote
SmsReceiver arg = new SmsReceiver();
show_sms = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_sms); 
show_sms.setText(arg.str);

-------------------------------------
The Return is null

Comment: what is the type of str ? and what is expected type in the method makeText(x, str, x) ?

Comment: str is String 
Toast.makeText....
shows the SMS when it is received

Comment: Do you mean you want to display the SMS in `MainActivity`? Is the `Toast` showing correctly?

Comment: No. I mean that I put the entire message after the loop inside a String variable .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your code, it worked well when I called the message from the MainActivity Class. But, indeed, I want to use it in the same class

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
```

I wrote

```
set_sms();

       //---display the new SMS message---
       Intent intentHome = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
       intentHome.putExtra("msgContent", message);

       intentHome.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(intentHome);
   }                         

void set_sms()
{
   Activity x = new Activity() ; 
    Bundle extras = x.getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
message = extras.getString("msgContent");
}

}
```

But, There is always an error